# Mysql Stored Procedure doesnt return out id

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to perform transactional inserts , but i do not understand the problem because i couldnt see the error. I read carefully the mysql instructions for performing transactional procedure.
The problem is there is no return out header id, How do I mitigate this issue?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `add_payment`(IN `transaction_no` VARCHAR(50),
  IN `transaction_type_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED,
  IN `distributor_details_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED,
  IN `customer_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED,
  IN `amount` DECIMAL(18,8),
  IN `salesman_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED,
  IN `created_datetime` DATETIME,
  OUT `payment_header_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED)
BEGIN

  DECLARE transaction_code_id INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE transaction_x_payment_header_id INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE payment_details_id INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

  DECLARE user_id MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;


#
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
      SET payment_header_id = 0;
      ROLLBACK ;
    END;

  START TRANSACTION;
  # GET USER TO HAVE A REFERENCE WHOS DOING THIS
  SET user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM salesman_x_user WHERE salesman_id = salesman_id);

  # INSERT PAYMENT HEADER FIRST TO HAVE PAYMENT HEADER ID
  INSERT INTO `payment_header` (`no` , `created_datetime`) VALUES(transaction_no , created_datetime);

  SET payment_header_id = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
  COMMIT;


END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid naming variables and parameters as columns of your tables.

See the following adapted example:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `payment_header`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `payment_header`(
    ->   `payment_header_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `no` VARCHAR(50),
    ->   `created_datetime` DATETIME,
    ->   UNIQUE KEY (`no`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_payment`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `add_payment` (
    ->   IN `_transaction_no` VARCHAR(50),
    ->   IN `_transaction_type_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED,
    ->   IN `_distributor_details_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED,
    ->   IN `_customer_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED,
    ->   IN `_amount` DECIMAL(18, 8),
    ->   IN `_salesman_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED,
    ->   IN `_created_datetime` DATETIME,
    ->   OUT `_payment_header_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED
    -> )
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `transaction_code_id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    ->   DECLARE `transaction_x_payment_header_id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    ->   DECLARE `payment_details_id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    ->   DECLARE `user_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    -> 
    ->   DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    ->     BEGIN
    ->       SET `_payment_header_id` = 0;
    ->       ROLLBACK;
    ->     END;
    -> 
    ->   START TRANSACTION;
    ->   # GET USER TO HAVE A REFERENCE WHOS DOING THIS
    ->   /*SET `user_id` = (SELECT `user_id`
   /*>                      FROM `salesman_x_user`
   /*>                      WHERE `salesman_id` = `_salesman_id`);*/
    -> 
    ->   # INSERT PAYMENT HEADER FIRST TO HAVE PAYMENT HEADER ID
    ->   INSERT INTO `payment_header` (`no` , `created_datetime`)
    ->   VALUES (`_transaction_no`, `_created_datetime`);
    -> 
    ->   SET `_payment_header_id` = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    ->   COMMIT;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `add_payment`(
    ->   '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    ->   NULL,
    ->   NULL,
    ->   NULL,
    ->   NULL,
    ->   NULL,
    ->   NOW(),
    ->   @`payment_header_id`
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`payment_header_id`;
+----------------------+
| @`payment_header_id` |
+----------------------+
|                    1 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    -> `payment_header_id`,
    ->     `no`,
    ->     `created_datetime`
    -> FROM
    -> `payment_header`;
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| payment_header_id | no                                                 | created_datetime    |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|                 1 | 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 | 2000-01-01 00:00:01 |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `add_payment`(
    ->   '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    ->   NULL,
    ->   NULL,
    ->   NULL,
    ->   NULL,
    ->   NULL,
    ->   NOW(),
    ->   @`payment_header_id`
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`payment_header_id`;
+----------------------+
| @`payment_header_id` |
+----------------------+
|                    0 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    -> `payment_header_id`,
    ->     `no`,
    ->     `created_datetime`
    -> FROM
    -> `payment_header`;
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| payment_header_id | no                                                 | created_datetime    |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|                 1 | 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 | 2000-01-01 00:00:01 |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mLY3Qw6KFEiRimWfKpvWRJ/1).